Audio Not Working on Droidcam on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
After follow all instructions on the official website for droidcam, I can't seem to get audio to work. No visible errors pop, it is just that when I open pavucontrol and change the entries in the 'Configuration' tab to 'Pro Audio', I don't see any change.
This is the exact order of things I have typed into the terminal:
cd /tmp/
wget -O droidcam_latest.zip https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_2.1.3.zip
# sha1sum: 2646edd5ad2cfb046c9c695fa6d564d33be0f38b
unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam
cd droidcam && sudo ./install-client

sudo apt install libappindicator3-1

sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r` gcc make

sudo ./install-video

sudo ./install-sound

sudo apt-get install adb



